# how to find the maximum length of a column in a datatable using linq

Tags: asp.net

how to find the maximum length of a column in a datatable using linq in vb.net
 I want the max length in col1 5.How can i achieve this using linq

```
    Dim DT as new datatable
    datatable.columns.add("Col1")
    datatable.rows(0).item("Col1")="123"`val inserted
    datatable.rows(1).item("Col1")="1234"`val inserted
    datatable.rows(2).item("Col1")="12345`val inserted
```

Comment: length of columns means????????

Comment: max length of a string of all rows in a column.so in my eg for col1 i should get 5 as the max length.hope u r clear

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it is VB.Net one.

```
Dim datatable As New DataTable()
datatable.Columns.Add("Col1")
datatable.Rows.Add("123")
datatable.Rows.Add("123456")
datatable.Rows.Add("12345")
datatable.Rows.Add("Z")
datatable.Rows.Add("ABCD")
datatable.Rows.Add("Cd")
datatable.Rows.Add("Z")
datatable.Rows.Add("Za123456Akwef")`

datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Col1").Length).Max
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is C# one.

```
DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
datatable.Columns.Add("Col1");
datatable.Rows.Add("123");  
datatable.Rows.Add("123456");
datatable.Rows.Add("12345");
int maxlength = 0;
datatable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToList()
    .ForEach(ss => { maxlength = Convert.ToString(ss.ItemArray[0]).Length > maxlength ? 
        Convert.ToString(ss.ItemArray[0]).Length : maxlength; });
```

it will result
6

Vb.Net code snippet (translated, not much sure about syntax).

```
Dim datatable As New DataTable()
datatable.Columns.Add("Col1")
datatable.Rows.Add("123")
datatable.Rows.Add("123456")
datatable.Rows.Add("12345")
Dim maxlength As Integer = 0
datatable.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)().ToList().ForEach(Function(ss) 
maxlength = If(Convert.ToString(ss.ItemArray(0)).Length > maxlength, Convert.ToString(ss.ItemArray(0)).Length, maxlength)

End Function)
```

Hope this help..

Comment: Thank You.How can i get   the length of all columns of a datatable  into a list.Is it possible using linq?

Comment: loop through ss.ItemArray[i], counting the table.columns.Count - 1 and then you will be able to do tis..

Comment: Rows.OfType is undefined in C#

Comment: @Fandango68: Import System.Linq in your project file for using this extension methods

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim DT as new DataTable
DT.columns.add("Col1")
DT.rows(0).item("Col1")="123"
DT.rows(1).item("Col1")="1234"
DT.rows(2).item("Col1")="12345" 
Dim maxlength As Integer = DT.AsEnumerable.Max(Function() x("Col1").ToString.Length)
```